# App crashed when return to previous activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, indexoutofboundsexception

I really have no idea to solve this problem.

In one of my Activity, it has a `ListView`. When the list is clicked, it will intent to new Activity for edit. The problem now is when I press the back button in emulator, app crashed.

```
       listViewUpdate.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    mClickedPosition=position; // update
                    // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding listview_item_row in the result set
                    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    // Get the state's capital from this listview_item_row in the database.
                    ID =
                            cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Edit_Details.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ID", ID);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);


                }
            });


 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
        if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
            ReceiveProject = data.getStringExtra("project1");
            ReceiveDescription = data.getStringExtra("description");
            ReceiveProgress = data.getIntExtra("progress", 0);
            ReceiveTimeIn = data.getStringExtra("timeIn");
            ReceiveTimeOut = data.getStringExtra("timeOut");
           if (mClickedPosition == -1) {  // if icon clicked
                if (objMyCustomBaseAdapter != null)
                    objMyCustomBaseAdapter.addNewItem(ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, ReceiveProgress, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut);

            } else {
                if (objMyCustomBaseAdapter != null)
                    objMyCustomBaseAdapter.changeItem(mClickedPosition, ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, ReceiveProgress, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut);

            }

        }

    }
```

**Edit_Details.java**

```
  save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // return values to previous activity
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "D", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                project1 = Project2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                description = Description.getText().toString();
                progress = seekBar.getProgress();
                returnIntent.putExtra("project1", project1);
                returnIntent.putExtra("description", description);
                returnIntent.putExtra("progress", progress);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), progress + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                returnIntent.putExtra("timeIn", timeIn);
                returnIntent.putExtra("timeOut", timeOut);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();

            }


        });

 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

**MyCustomBaseAdapter**

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   // for ListView


        private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;

        FrameLayout footerLayout;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        ListView listview;
       AbsoluteLayout footer;

        public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results,ListView listview,FrameLayout footerLayout,AbsoluteLayout footer) {
            searchArrayList = results;
            this.listview=listview;
            this.footerLayout=footerLayout;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
             this.footer=footer;
            addOrRemoveFooter();
        }

    public void addOrRemoveFooter(){
        if(searchArrayList.size() == 0 && listview.getFooterViewsCount() > 0){
           listview.removeFooterView(footer);
            listview.removeFooterView(footerLayout);
            Log.e("Search",searchArrayList.size()+"");
        }else if(listview.getFooterViewsCount() == 0 && searchArrayList.size()>0){
            listview.addFooterView(footer);
            listview.addFooterView(footerLayout);
            Log.e("Search1",searchArrayList.size()+"");
        }
        else if(searchArrayList.size()!=0)
        {
            listview.addFooterView(footer);
            listview.addFooterView(footerLayout);
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return searchArrayList.size();
    }

       public String getFistTime() {
        SearchResults firstTime = this.searchArrayList.get(0);
        return firstTime.getTimeIn();
       }

    public String getLastTime() {
        SearchResults lastTime = this.searchArrayList.get(searchArrayList.size() - 1);
        return lastTime.getTimeOut();
    }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return searchArrayList.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

       public void addNewItem(String P,String D,int Per,String I,String O)
      {
        SearchResults obj = new SearchResults();
          obj.setProject(P);
          obj.setProgress(" Progress : " + Per);
          obj.setTimeIn(" Time In : " + I);
          obj.setTimeOut(" Time Out : " + O);
          obj.setDescription(" Work Description : " + D);
          searchArrayList.add(obj);
          this. notifyDataSetChanged();

         addOrRemoveFooter();

    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        searchArrayList.remove(position);
        addOrRemoveFooter();
        this. notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    public void changeItem(int m,String P,String D,int Per,String TI,String TO)
    {
        SearchResults obj = new SearchResults();
        obj.setProject(P);
        obj.setDescription(" Work Description : " + D);
        obj.setProgress(" Progress : " + Per);
        obj.setTimeIn(" Time In : " + TI);
        obj.setTimeOut(" Time Out : " + TO);
        searchArrayList.set(m,obj);
        this. notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtProject= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListProject);
                holder.txtDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListDescription);
                holder.txtProgress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListProgress);
                holder.txtIn=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListTimeIn);
                holder.txtOut=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListTimeOut);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.txtProject.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getProject());
            holder.txtDescription.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getDescription());
            holder.txtProgress.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getProgress());
            holder.txtIn.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getTimeIn());
            holder.txtOut.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getTimeOut());

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtProject;
            TextView txtDescription;
            TextView txtProgress;
            TextView txtIn;
            TextView txtOut;
        }
    }
```

**LogCat error**

```
12-07 09:10:46.143    3000-3000/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project.myapplication, PID: 3000
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=196609, result=0, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.example.project.myapplication/com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.ActivityB}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:481)
            at com.example.project.myapplication.Adapter.MyCustomBaseAdapter.changeItem(MyCustomBaseAdapter.java:111)
            at com.example.project.myapplication.GUI.Edit_WorkDetails.onActivityResult(Edit_WorkDetails.java:138)
```

This two line shows error

```
  searchArrayList.set(m,obj);
```

**and**   `objMyCustomBaseAdapter.changeItem(mClickedPosition, ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, ReceiveProgress, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut);`

If the save button in Edit_Details is pressed, only the `changeItem()` will get called. But I wanted to return to previous activity only. Anyone can help me ??? Thanks

Comment: Horrible variable names. Put something meaningful as variable names, not going to read this code. Your problem is, as the stacktrace says, you're accessing index 0 of a list of size 0.

Comment: What meaningful variable names you expect it to be ? I have set all my variable  to a name such like  `ReceiveProject`,  `ReceiveDescription` instead of `a` and `b`. If you **not interested to read my code and not willing to help**, you can just walk away, no need downvotes my question

Comment: I wouldn't be reading your comments if I wasn't willing to help. Just note that you're the one asking for help here. Just advising you on how to get better help. Your code doesn't make it easy for anyone to help you. How are `P`, `D`, `m`, `Per` meaningful? Also note that I already stated where your problem lies, but looks like you're not interested in that.

Comment: check the value of mClickedPosition that it must not greater than or equl to the size of arraylist

Comment: Just a notice, please read this guideline for code convention, i couldn't read your code https://github.com/ribot/android-guidelines/blob/master/project_and_code_guidelines.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to check resultcode in onActivityResult first like below

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
            ReceiveProject = data.getStringExtra("project1");
            ReceiveDescription = data.getStringExtra("description");
            ReceiveProgress = data.getIntExtra("progress", 0);
            ReceiveTimeIn = data.getStringExtra("timeIn");
            ReceiveTimeOut = data.getStringExtra("timeOut");
            if (mClickedPosition == -1) {  // if icon clicked
                if (objMyCustomBaseAdapter != null)
                    objMyCustomBaseAdapter.addNewItem(ReceiveProject,  ReceiveDescription, ReceiveProgress, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut);
        } else {
                if (objMyCustomBaseAdapter != null)
                objMyCustomBaseAdapter.changeItem(mClickedPosition, ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, ReceiveProgress, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How should I declare the `RESULT_OK` ?

Comment: You can check by writing Activity.RESULT_OK. As you have set result Activity.RESULT_OK on save button's click and Activity.RESULT_CANCELED on onBackPessed method.If you click back button then result will be set as Activity.RESULT_CANCELED and if you check Activity.RESULT_OK in OnActivityResult, it won't go inside condition and app will not crash.

Comment: how should I set the `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` ? I use your code and my app won't crashed when back button is pressed. But it crashed and shows the same logcat error when save button clicked.

Comment: You can set Activity.RESULT_CANCELED the same way you set Activity.RESULT_OK.If app crashes on Save button then something must be wrong with the data you set.

Answer (score 2):

Check the value of mClickedPosition that it must not greater than or eqaul to the size of searchArrayList.

Check this line in LogCat 
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

it indicates that your ArrayList is empty and you are accessing its 0 index's object

One more thing is in OnActivityResult you must check the resultcode returned to your activity like this

```
@Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
            if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                    ReceiveProject = bundle.getStringExtra("project1");
                    ReceiveDescription = bundle.getStringExtra("description");
                    ReceiveProgress = bundle.getIntExtra("progress", 0);
                    ReceiveTimeIn = bundle.getStringExtra("timeIn");
                    ReceiveTimeOut = bundle.getStringExtra("timeOut");
                    if (mClickedPosition == -1) {  // if icon clicked
                        if (objMyCustomBaseAdapter != null)
                            objMyCustomBaseAdapter.addNewItem(ReceiveProject, 
                                    ReceiveDescription, ReceiveProgress, 
                                    ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut);
                    } else {
                        if (objMyCustomBaseAdapter != null)
                            objMyCustomBaseAdapter.changeItem(mClickedPosition, 
                                    ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, 
                                    ReceiveProgress, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: How should I declare the `RESULT_OK` ?

Comment: RESULT_OK is a static variable of Activity class you can simply use it like Activity.RESULT_OK

Comment: I use your code and my app won't crashed when back button is pressed. But it crashed and shows the same logcat error when save button clicked.

Comment: I edited my answer you should use Bundle bundle = data.getExtras(); to get Extras of intent .and then fetch your data from that bundle like I do.Because intent.putExtras() stores your result in a bundle which you can fetch by calling the method intent.getExtras();