# Kotlin Retrofit return null to recylerView in .enqueue

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

So I'm trying to get data from an API with retrofit into a recycler view adapter. Everything works perfectly such as showing a list of data retrieve into list items. However, when press on the list item of the recycler view and intent to another activity and intent back to the original activity, the app crashed. With the error below :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.marcusneo.stockportfolio, PID: 7586
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.marcusneo.stockportfolio.MainActivity$getPortData$1.onResponse(MainActivity.kt:191)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1
```

The line 191 that cause the error is the "response.body()!!.annualReports.let { detailAdapter.setData(it) }"

Below is the function of the retrieve data from API, it runs in onCreate()

```
private fun getDetailsData(keywords: String){
        val retrofitData = retrofitBuilder.getCompDetails(keywords)
        retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<IncomeState?> {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<IncomeState?>, response: Response<IncomeState?>) {

                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    if(response.body() != null){
                        response.body()!!.annualReports.let { detailAdapter.setData(it) }
                        binding.loadingDetail.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.rvDetails.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    } else {
                        binding.loadingDetail.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        binding.rvDetails.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("Response Errr", response.errorBody().toString())
                }

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<IncomeState?>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("MainActivity","onFailure: " + t.message)
            }
        })
        detailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

How do I make the response.body()!! to not null?

Comment: You may find [this answer ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34130935/8262293) useful .

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid *NullPointerException*, define a variable such as `val responseBody = responde.body()` and then check if the variable is not null:

```
if (response.isSuccessful) {
    val responseBody = response.body()
    if (responseBody != null) {
        responseBody.annualReports.let { detailAdapter.setData(it) }
        binding.loadingDetail.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.rvDetails.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        binding.loadingDetail.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.rvDetails.visibility = View.GONE
    }
} else {
    Log.d("Response Errr", response.errorBody().toString())
}
```

Comment: Tried this, same error appear.